# Delphi - moving overlapping TShapes

Tags: delphi, events, shapes, onmousedown

I've needed own triangle shape so, I inherited my triangle class form TShape and override paint method. Everything works fine, but I need to move this shapes with mouse. I set the method for every shape handling onMouseDown event. Moving work also fine. But If two shapes overlaps (shapes are in fact rectangles with some transparent areas), that the top's shape transparent area is over another shape, then the top shape moves instead of the shape below. It's correct, that is how Delphi works. But it's not intuitive for the user. How can I achieve that? Is there possibility to not remove the event from event queue and sent it to underlying shapes, if yes it would be simple?

Comment: Drawing animations by moving controls (even graphic controls) on a form is bad. If I were you, I'd store the scene in some custom data structure, and then draw the form completely manually. Then there is no restriction holding you back -- you can implement any mouse interface you wish.

Answer (score 14):

A 'simple sample redesign' per my comment follows.

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

const
  NUM_TRIANGLES = 10;
  COLORS: array[0..12] of integer = (clRed, clGreen, clBlue, clYellow, clFuchsia,
    clLime, clGray, clSilver, clBlack, clMaroon, clNavy, clSkyBlue, clMoneyGreen);

type
  TTriangle = record
    X, Y: integer; // bottom-left corner
    Base, Height: integer;
    Color: TColor;
  end;

  TTriangles = array[0..NUM_TRIANGLES - 1] of TTriangle;

  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FTriangles: TTriangles;
    FDragOffset: TPoint;
    FTriangleActive: boolean;
    function GetTriangleAt(AX, AY: Integer): Integer;
    function IsMouseDown: boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

uses Math;

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  FTriangleActive := false;
  Randomize;
  for i := 0 to NUM_TRIANGLES - 1 do
    with FTriangles[i] do
    begin
      base := 40 + Random(80);
      height := 40 + Random(40);
      X := Random(ClientWidth - base);
      Y := height + Random(ClientHeight - height);
      Color := RandomFrom(COLORS);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  TriangleIndex: integer;
  TempTriangle: TTriangle;
  i: Integer;
begin
  TriangleIndex := GetTriangleAt(X, Y);
  if TriangleIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    FDragOffset.X := X - FTriangles[TriangleIndex].X;
    FDragOffset.Y := Y - FTriangles[TriangleIndex].Y;
    TempTriangle := FTriangles[TriangleIndex];
    for i := TriangleIndex to NUM_TRIANGLES - 2 do
      FTriangles[i] := FTriangles[i + 1];
    FTriangles[NUM_TRIANGLES - 1] := TempTriangle;
    Invalidate;
  end;
  FTriangleActive := TriangleIndex <> -1;
end;

function TForm4.IsMouseDown: boolean;
begin
  result := GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) and $8000 <> 0;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsMouseDown and FTriangleActive then
  begin
    FTriangles[high(FTriangles)].X := X - FDragOffset.X;
    FTriangles[high(FTriangles)].Y := Y - FDragOffset.Y;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FTriangleActive := false;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Vertices: array of TPoint;
begin
  SetLength(Vertices, 3);
  for i := 0 to NUM_TRIANGLES - 1 do
    with FTriangles[i] do
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
      Vertices[0] := Point(X, Y);
      Vertices[1] := Point(X + Base, Y);
      Vertices[2] := Point(X + Base div 2, Y - Height);
      Canvas.Polygon(Vertices);
    end;
end;

function TForm4.GetTriangleAt(AX, AY: Integer): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  for i := NUM_TRIANGLES - 1 downto 0 do
    with FTriangles[i] do
      if InRange(AY, Y - Height, Y) and
        InRange(AX, round(X + (Base / 2) * (Y - AY) / Height),
          round(X + Base - (Base / 2) * (Y - AY) / Height)) then
        Exit(i);
end;

end.
```

Don't forget to set the form's `DoubleBuffered` to `true`.

Compiled sample demo: https://privat.rejbrand.se/MovingTriangles.exe

Comment: I know it's been a long time since you posted this answer, but maybe you could explain your `InRange` for `AX` min/max calculation? that kind of blows my mind, I havent done math or geometry in a long time thought. After more staring I think I've started to understand. You scale down half of the potential smaller triangle `Base` with given `AY` by dividing `Y-AY` (small triangle height) by `Height`? But how do you know that cutting that from two sides will mean that `X` is in that range? I did some drawing and it is true and now i see it, but it's not as clear when done programmatically though

Answer (score 0):

Test whether the mouse click is within the triangle area before initiate moving the shape. That requires some math, but you could also misuse the WinAPI PtInRegion function by creating a temporary region, as follows:

```
function PtInPolygon(const Pt: TPoint; const Points: array of TPoint): Boolean;
var
  Region: HRGN;
begin
  Region := CreatePolygonRgn(Points[0], Length(Points), WINDING);
  try
    Result := PtInRegion(Region, Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  finally
    DeleteObject(Region);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  StartMove: Boolean;
begin
  StartMove := PtInPolygon(Point(X, Y), [Point(100, 0), Point(200, 200),
    Point(0, 200)]);
  ...
```