# Random not properly working inside a loop

Tags: pascal, lazarus

- I'm sorry incase this is a bad question, I'm only working with Pascal because of some computer class homework where we have to draw a picture using Pascal *

I'm basicly trying to draw stars at random locations, the problem I'm facing right now is that when I call the procedure inside a loop only 1-2 stars are being drawn even though the loop runs 1000 times.

I've tried generating one by one by clicking a button, and it worked so I'm assuming it has something to do with Random not properly working inside a loop.

```
     randomize();

     i := 0;
      while i < 1000 do begin
         x := random(Image1.Width);
         y := random(Image1.Height);

         Ellipse(x, y, x+3, y+3);

         i += 1;
      end;
```

Comment: `Random` works just fine within a loop. In fact, the function has no idea it is being called from inside a loop -- it has no way of finding out. (And that applies to most languages.) So your problem lies elsewhere. A few off-topic hints: Don't call `Randomize` repeatedly. Only call it *once* when your application starts (or at least before you need to use random numbers). Also, notice that Pascal has no `+=` operator. But I think that is a FreePascal extension. Most Pascal developers these days use Delphi, and there there is no operator `+=`. Also, I'd use a `for` loop here.

Comment: Where are you using this code? If you are writing a native Win32 application using GDI, you should only paint the window when you receive a `WM_PAINT` message. In Delphi, that typically corresponds to the `OnPaint` event handler. And btw, here is my standard example of how to draw using the GDI in Delphi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224075/282848

Comment: wow, it was actually just the += operator that caused this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call to `Randomize`. When placed in a loop it will reinitialize the pseudo random number generator based on the system time, which may not have changed since the previous call.

If you are to call `Randomize` call it once at startup.

Comment: it was actually just the += operator that caused the issue I was having, I already removed the randomize call in the for loop

Comment: The code in the question contains a call to Randomize inside the loop. I'm not able to see your screen.

Comment: I know, but the guy that anwsered before you already pointed that out, thanks anyways for trying to help!

Comment: That was a comment. This is an answer. Might be worth learning a bit about how answers work, how they are accepted etc. The += 1 should work fine in fpc. I'd regard Inc as idiomatic in Pascal however.